# How do add Quandl package to Julia

Tags: package, julia, quandl

I'm trying to add the Quandl package (query finance and economic data) like this:

`using Pkg
Pkg.add("Quandl")`

which gets me this:

`Updating registry at ~/.julia/registries/General`

`Updating git-repo`https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`

`[1mFetching: [========================================>]  100.0 %[==========>                              ]  23.3 %]  46.4 % %>   ]  90.2 %`

`The following package names could not be resolved:`

`* Quandl (not found in project, manifest or registry)`

Anyone know what's going on here? Am I doing something wrong or is there a problem with the package?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that `Quandl` is not registered in Julia's general registry, and can therefore not be added directly by typing it's name in the package manager.

You can still add it from its URL, are you referring to this package:

https://github.com/milktrader/Quandl.jl?

If so you can do `Pkg.add("https://github.com/milktrader/Quandl.jl")` to add it from GitHub.

It looks however like the package is unmaintained, as it hasn't been updated for three years, and therefore is unlikely to work with Julia versions post 1.0.

If it turns out it doesn't work but you need the package, you can try installing Julia 0.7, which can give you deprecation warnings to tell you about the syntax changes to get it to work with Julia 1.0+.

Comment: `Pkg.add("https://github.com/milktrader/Quandl.jl")`

caused 

`https://github.com/milktrader/Quandl.jl is not a valid package name
The argument appears to be a URL or path, perhaps you meant Pkg.add(PackageSpec(url="...")) or Pkg.add(PackageSpec(path="..."))`

So

`Pkg.add(PackageSpec(url="https://github.com/milktrader/Quandl.jl"))`

caused

`Cloning git-repo `https://github.com/milktrader/Quandl.jl`

Then

`could not find project file in package at https://github.com/milktrader/Quandl.jl`

Maybe the alleged missing project file is due to the package not being maintained?

Comment: Yes that's correct - project files are only required for more recent Julia versions, so very old and unmaintained packages will not have them. As I said this shouldn't be an issue if you use Julia 0.7.

Comment: Quandl provides an API you can query directly. The package Quandl.jl is a practically defunct wrapper for those calls, you should only need a few lines from the source to access the data. The package `HTTP.jl` is most useful for this.